# Antlr4 Listener subtree check condition

Tags: go, antlr4

I'm new to Antlr, pardon me for basic question, I'm trying to validate the below statement, like `if while_condition contains f_lastmove.. do something` The while_condition can have other conditions as well. How can I drill down the while_condition? I'm using Listener Pattern with Golang.
[image: ESQL While Statement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Go, but in Java you could do something like this:

```java
// In this example, the grammar is called `T.g4`
class WhileLastMoveListener extends TBaseListener {

    private boolean insideWhileCondition = false;
    
    @Override 
    public void enterWhile_condition(TParser.While_conditionContext ctx) { 
        this.insideWhileCondition = true;
    }

    @Override 
    public void exitWhile_condition(TParser.While_conditionContext ctx) {
        this.insideWhileCondition = false;
    }

    @Override 
    public void enterF_lastmove(TParser.F_lastmoveContext ctx) {
        if (this.insideWhileCondition) {
            // Found a `f_lastmove` rule inside a while `while_condition`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bart! This worked! Of course I had to use Go syntax :-P

Comment: You're welcome @DipD. You could also answer your own question and include the Go syntax: might be beneficial for others.